# swift Alamofire , Json parsing in Array

Tags: json, swift

[image]

I wan't picture in json Array get bsList i use Codable & Alamofire

picture :

response

i dont have get bsList key

my solution is

```
   struct data: Codable {
            var message:String?
            var req_id: String?
            var result :String?
            var data : [String]?
            var bsList : [bsList]?
          
        }
        struct bsList : Codable{
            var bs_addr1:String?
            var bs_addr2:String?
            var bs_id:Int?
            var bs_key:String?
            var bs_nm:String?
            var dist:Double?
            
        }
```

but console is "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

help me plz!!!

Comment: plz check my photo attache

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your post and type out your code.

Comment: First of all don't print `error.localizedDescription`, never do that. `print(error)` gives you the actual error (which is pretty obvious by the way). And please name structs with starting uppercase letter according to the naming convention. And why are all struct members in `bsList` optional? The JSON clearly sends always all keys in all dictionaries.